# Validate XML documents with XML Schema in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, schema

I am writing a PL/SQL procedure which will validate XML type files against a schema. The XML documents are stored, in the Oracle database, in an XMLType table `XML_TABLE` with a single column, `SYS_NC_ROWINFO$`. The Schema I wish to use is also contained within the same Oracle database, as an XML Schema (CLOB), and its URL is `StructuredProductsXMLSchema0v0.1.49.xsd`.

At the moment, I am simply trying to validate just 1 of the XML documents (hence `rownum = 1` in the code below), using the simplest possible method. Below is the procedure I have created:

```
create or replace procedure XML_FILE_VALIDATOR is

XDATA XMLType;

begin

  select SYS_NC_ROWINFO$ into XDATA
  from XML_TABLE
  where rownum = 1;

  XDATA.isSchemaValid('StructuredProductsXMLSchema0v0.1.49.xsd');
  if XDATA.isSchemaValid = 1 then
    dbms_output.put_line ('XML document is VALID');

  else
    dbms_output.put_line ('XML document is INVALID => '||sqlerrm);

  end if;
end;
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error message:

**PLS-00221: 'ISSCHEMAVALID' is not a procedure or is undefined**

Any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `XDATA.isSchemaValid('<*.xsd>')` is a function and not a procedure, you will need to save its value in a variable

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SudiptaMondal - how can I implement this into my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a [link to the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb08tra.htm). I don't know your version, but it shouldn't matter that much.

> PL/SQL function `isSchemaValid` checks if the input instance conforms to a specified XML schema.

So this is a member function, not a procedure. That's why your code fails at line `XDATA.isSchemaValid('StructuredProductsXMLSchema0v0.1.49.xsd');`.

You don't need it.

Then you have an if-statement, where you are trying to use it as a function (correct) but not passing arguments (which is not going to work).

> If an XML schema URL is not specified and the XML document is schema-based, then the conformance is checked against the own schema of the XMLType instance.

That is not your case, as your XML documents are not schema-based.

```
if XDATA.isSchemaValid('StructuredProductsXMLSchema0v0.1.49.xsd') then
....
end if
```

That would probably work. As a side note, I'm not sure if the url is correct though (they usually look a bit different, but you will be able to figure it out, just check in `ALL_XML_SCHEMAS`).

Comment: Thank you for your response - the procedure now seems to run. Why will other functions such as 'schemaValidate' not wok in the same way?

Comment: `schemaValidate` is not a function, but a procedure. It does not return anything, so you call it without assignment: `xmltype_Object.schemaValidate`.